# ebay sdk can't connect

Tags: python, api, sdk

Seem to be getting a connection error based on the trace but can't figure out why? Here is my simple script:

```
import ebaysdk
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError

api = Connection(config_file='ebay.yaml', domain='api.sandbox.ebay.com')

api_request = {
            #'keywords': u'niño',
            'keywords': u'GRAMMY Foundation®',
            'itemFilter': [
                {'name': 'Condition',
                 'value': 'Used'},
                {'name': 'LocatedIn',
                 'value': 'GB'},
            ],
            'affiliate': {'trackingId': 1},
            'sortOrder': 'CountryDescending',
        }


response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', api_request)
```

Here's the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebaysdk/connection.py", line 127, in execute
self.error_check()
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ebaysdk/connection.py", line 223, in error_check
raise ConnectionError(estr, self.response)
ebaysdk.exception.ConnectionError: 'findItemsAdvanced: Accepted'

Here is my .yaml file:

```
name: ebay_api_config

# Trading API Sandbox - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/trading-api
api.sandbox.ebay.com:
    compatability: 719
     appid: APPID
    certid: CERTID
    devid: DEVID
    token: TOKEN
    https: 1

# Trading API - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/trading-api
api.ebay.com:
    compatability: 719
    appid: APPID
    certid: CERTID
    devid: DEVID
    token: TOKEN
    https: 1

# Finding API - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/finding-api
svcs.ebay.com:
    appid: APPID
    version: 1.0.0
    https: 1

# Shopping API - https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/shopping-api
open.api.ebay.com:
    appid: APPID
    https: 1
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your domain in connection function to :

```
domain='svcs.sandbox.ebay.com'
```